# I m just try to make Free energy using buoyancy

Tags: energy-conservation, power, buoyancy, perpetual-motion

Can I make power (electricity ) using buoyancy see diagram. if this diagram is possible then how much power i get . I just need formula for upwards speed.
[image]

Comment: This very same diagram has already been posted here in the past. Please change the record: no free lunch!

Comment: Also, don't believe a diagram which misspells "generator", "through" and "lighter".

Answer (score 1):

The pressure at the bottom of the water tank is large. You have to push the balls in against this pressure - that is exactly as much work as you will get back.

No free lunch in nature. Sorry.

Comment: If I use injection like mechanism which directly inject inside every time then it's possible

Comment: Nope - you need to make a ball appear in a place where there is pressure. Going from low pressure (atmosphere) to high pressure (bottom of the tank) will take work.

Comment: @user99699 the injection mechanism will require power. You have to inject against the weight of the water and against the friction of the lower membrane, and only recover energy from the pressure/bouyancy. The machine won't even power its own injector, let alone a generator.

Comment: @user99699 - Here's a word of advice. If you want to disagree with someone, try asking a question like "If I use injection like mechanism, won't it be possible?". That way, your suggestion that such a mechanism WOULD work will not sound quite so ignorant of how things work. Simply asserting that something is true when it isn't doesn't convince many folk that they should listen to you.